# Node.js HTTPS Hello world server on IE8

Tags: node.js, ssl, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to run this example HTTPS server from [Node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html).

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('test/fixtures/keys/agent2-cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
}).listen(8000);
```

`https://localhost:8000/` works fine with Firefox 29 but not with IE8. "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage."

I also tried [this support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968089) from Microsoft but nothing worked.

Is that a known issue?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be certainly working. Double check that the server is up when you try with IE8

Comment: Yep server is up since I can access through Firefox. Maybe IE8 doesn't support the pem files ?

Answer (score 0):

There maybe problem with certificates which is self-made. My IE8 writes:

```
There is a problem with this website's security certificate.
```

You should click:

```
Continue to this website (not recommended).
```

And hello world will be displayed.